# AWS: Can I create a new SES email address and forward it to more than one email address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

GoDaddy has been migrating Workspace emails to Microsoft since 2020. When a Workspace email address is migrated all Workspace forwarding emails for that email account will be deleted.

I have a GoDaddy domain with only a workspace forwarding email address that forwards to two non-GoDaddy email addresses. I want to replicate what I have with that forwarding email address using AWS before that forwarding email address is deleted. The domain and the forwarding email address are verified entities in SES. Some CNAME and TXT DNS records are already on the domain.

I've read several pages related to setting up an existing GoDaddy pop email address in AWS and doing steps to allow it to forward to one or more email addresses. Here are three of the pages I read:

https://codethump.com/tutorials/send-receive-domain-email-aws-setup/

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/easily-create-email-addresses-for-your-route53-custom-domain-589d099dd0f2

https://medium.com/@jonnyux/simple-email-forwarding-with-aws-f88b9ffdb60a

I only have a forwarding email address. I don't know if my current SES setup for the forwarding email address is enough to keep that email address when the GoDaddy forwarding email address is deleted. If not, can I create that email address in AWS and use it instead of the GoDaddy created email address?